# Oracle OCI multiple querys in the same statement

Tags: oracle-call-interface

I'm trying to implement a driver that connect a webserver to oracle using the OCI API.
is it possible to sent multiple querys in the same time (the same string) and receive responses (multiple result sets)
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This advanced concept can be used for different database connections. Multiple connection pools can also be used when different priorities are assigned to users. Different service level guarantees can be implemented using connection pooling.

Try

```
OCISessionPoolCreate
```